# Subclassing UITableViewController for PopoverController

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a ViewController that is composed of a few different views on my screen.  A scrollView for text data, a TableView for some other data, etc.  In my app, I want to add a UIPopOverController to show a list of my data.  The current ViewController I am in is not a subclass of UITableViewController.  Do I have to create a separate subclass of UITableViewController in another file, and use an instance of that class in this ViewController?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying your question a little? I've tried to answer, but I'm not sure what you're trying to subclass or thinking about subclassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show any kind of `UIViewController` in a `UIPopoverController`. A table view is not at all required for displaying a Popover controller. If you want to display a `UITableviewController`, you most certainly can. Just pass it in to the popover controller.